# kafka broker Connection to INTERNAL_BROKER_DNS failed

Tags: apache-kafka, aws-msk

i have 3 kafka brokers in MSK. Two of them gives below error.

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.KafkaStorageException: Error while writing to checkpoint file LOG_DIR/__amazon_msk_connect_offsets_debezium-kafka-connector-x/leader-epoch-checkpoint
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No space left on device
```

And the other broker gives below error.

```
[2022-10-18 11:50:43,383] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Member connect-1-97b56132-1f54-46a4-91f1-8d31e61e18a9 in group __amazon_msk_connect_cluster_debezium-kafka-connector-x has failed, removing it from the group (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2022-10-18 11:50:43,383] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Stabilized group __amazon_msk_connect_cluster_debezium-kafka-connector-x generation 1115 (__consumer_offsets-18) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2022-10-18 11:50:43,387] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Assignment received from leader for group __amazon_msk_connect_cluster_debezium-kafka-connector-x for generation 1115 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2022-10-18 11:50:43,387] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Preparing to rebalance group __amazon_msk_connect_cluster_debezium-kafka-connector-x in state PreparingRebalance with old generation 1115 (__consumer_offsets-18) (reason: error when storing group assignment during SyncGroup (member: connect-1-9c20e001-f852-4007-8614-78a5c27207f6)) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2022-10-18 11:50:43,876] WARN [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=3, fetcherId=0] Error in response for fetch request (type=FetchRequest, replicaId=1, maxWait=500, minBytes=1, maxBytes=10485760, fetchData={test-0=PartitionData(fetchOffset=149547, logStartOffset=7151, maxBytes=1048576, currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[0], lastFetchedEpoch=Optional.empty), test-0=PartitionData(fetchOffset=74123, logStartOffset=826, maxBytes=1048576, currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[0], lastFetchedEpoch=Optional.empty)}, isolationLevel=READ_UNCOMMITTED, toForget=, metadata=(sessionId=INVALID, epoch=INITIAL), rackId=) (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
java.io.IOException: Connection to INTERNAL_BROKER_DNS (id: 3 rack: null) failed.
```

I want to know why i'm getting above error `Error in response for fetch request` ? What does it mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`No space left on device` - You need a larger EBS, or remove log segments from it manually, assuming you can SSH to it. If not, contact MSK Support.

Given that there are brokers failing with storage requirements, then other brokers will simply be unable to connect to them